# Можно ли autoincrement поле не использовать в Primary Key?

Tags: java, mysql

Есть таблица вида

```
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
user_id INT NOT NULL,
user_num INT NOT NULL
```

Можно ли изменить `Primary Key` на комбинацию полей `(user_id, user_num)`, оставив `id Auto Increment`.

Comment: Нет смысла. Всей разницы между primary key и unique index - первый идёт первым в списке индексов, является кластерным, и не может иметь в составе выражения NULLABLE полей/префиксов. В остальном - эквивалентны. Так что делайте `(user_id, user_num)` уникальным индексом, NOT NULL они уже заявлены, эффект будет тот же.

Answer (score 1):

Можно. `AuthoIncrement` просто дает вам возможность не париться о том, чтоб у вас не было дублей. К примеру часто вместо `AuthoIncrement` используется какой-то внешний `id`.

Поэтому вы можете спокойно создавать любой `id` в том числе и комбинацию полей, но тогда на вас ложится ответственность за их уникальность.

**UPD:** как дополнил @Akina При явном задании duplicated value вместе с AuthoIncrement вы можете так же получить дубликаты.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание. Дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если есть таблица то нельзя. А создать новую можно.